# Convolution of two three dimensional arrays with padding on one side too slow

Tags: python, numpy

In my current project I need to "**convolve**" two three dimensional arrays in a slightly unusual way:

Assume we have two three dimensional arrays A and B with the dimensions dimA and dimB (same for every axis). Now we want to create a third array C with the dimensions dimA+dimB for every axis.

The entries of C are computed as:

```
c_{x1+x2,y1+y2,z1+z2} += a_{x1,y1,z1} * b_{x2,y2,z2}
```

My current version is straightforward:

```
dimA = A.shape[0]
dimB = B.shape[0]
dimC = dimA+dimB

C = np.zeros((dimC,dimC,dimC))
for x1 in range(dimA):
    for x2 in range(dimB):
        for y1 in range(dimA):
            for y2 in range(dimB):
                for z1 in range(dimA):
                    for z2 in range(dimB):
                        x = x1+x2
                        y = y1+y2
                        z = z1+z2
                        C[x,y,z] += A[x1,y1,z1] * B[x2,y2,z2]
```

Unfortunately, this version is really slow and not usable.

My second version was:

```
C = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(A,B,mode="full")
```

But this computes only the elements `max(dimA,dimB)`

Has anyone a better idea?

Comment: "But this computes only the elements `max(dimA,dimB)`" - doesn't for me, it seems to me that it is your shape that is wrong.

Comment: What you are describing is what you should get with [`mode='same'`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html).

Comment: Hi Jaime, hi seberg, you are correct. With mode = 'same' I get an array of dim max(dimA,dimB) and with "full" I get an array with a dimension of dimA + dimB - 1 so one row,column is missing.

Comment: So my current solution is a padding by one row/column. This works really well. Thank your for the pointer.

Comment: but why dimA+dimB to begin with, that just leaves you 0s at the end.

Comment: Not sure why this question is rated so high. All possible solutions are mentioned in the comments. The output of convolve should be dimA + dimB - 1. The -1 says that atleast one row of A overlaps with atleast one row of B when you are doing convolution. If you do not have that, like @seberg said, the last row will be zero.

Comment: Yeah, this has been solved already in the comments. You never index the last element on any of the axes so it's going to be zero. Just use fftconvolve and then copy the result into a slightly larger zeros array if you need that.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using [Numba](https://github.com/numba/numba)? It's a package that allows you to wrap Python code that is usually slow with a JIT compiler. I took a quick stab at your problem using Numba and got a significant speed up. Using IPython's magic `timeit` magic function, the `custom_convolution` function took ~18 s, while Numba's optimized function took 10.4 ms. That's a **speed up of more than 1700**.

Here's how Numba is implemented.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, double

s = 15
array_a = np.random.rand(s ** 3).reshape(s, s, s)
array_b = np.random.rand(s ** 3).reshape(s, s, s)

# Original code
def custom_convolution(A, B):

    dimA = A.shape[0]
    dimB = B.shape[0]
    dimC = dimA + dimB

    C = np.zeros((dimC, dimC, dimC))
    for x1 in range(dimA):
        for x2 in range(dimB):
            for y1 in range(dimA):
                for y2 in range(dimB):
                    for z1 in range(dimA):
                        for z2 in range(dimB):
                            x = x1 + x2
                            y = y1 + y2
                            z = z1 + z2
                            C[x, y, z] += A[x1, y1, z1] * B[x2, y2, z2]
    return C

# Numba'ing the function with the JIT compiler
fast_convolution = jit(double[:, :, :](double[:, :, :],
                        double[:, :, :]))(custom_convolution)
```

If you compute the residual between the results of both functions you will get zeros. This means that the JIT implementation is working without any problems.

```
slow_result = custom_convolution(array_a, array_b) 
fast_result = fast_convolution(array_a, array_b)

print np.max(np.abs(slow_result - fast_result))
```

The output I get for this is `0.0`.

You can either install Numba into your current Python setup or try it quickly with the [AnacondaCE](http://continuum.io/downloads.html) package from continuum.io.

Last but not least, Numba's function is faster than the `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` function by a factor of a few.

Note: I'm using Anaconda and not AnacondaCE. There are some differences between the two packages for Numba's performance, but I don't think it will differ too much.

Answer (score 4):

The general rule is to use the correct algorithm for the job, which, unless the convolution kernel is short compared to the data, is an FFT based convolution (short roughly means less than log2(n) where n is the length of the data).

In your case, since you're convolving two equal sizes datasets, you probably want to be considering an FFT based convolution.

Clearly, `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` is being a touch deficient in this regard. Using a faster FFT algorithm, you can do much better by rolling your own convolution routine (it doesn't help that fftconvolve forces the transform size to powers of two, otherwise it could be monkey patched).

The following code uses [pyfftw](https://github.com/hgomersall/pyFFTW), my wrappers around [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org) and creates a custom convolution class, `CustomFFTConvolution`:

```
class CustomFFTConvolution(object):

    def __init__(self, A, B, threads=1):

        shape = (np.array(A.shape) + np.array(B.shape))-1

        if np.iscomplexobj(A) and np.iscomplexobj(B):
            self.fft_A_obj = pyfftw.builders.fftn(
                    A, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.fft_B_obj = pyfftw.builders.fftn(
                    B, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.ifft_obj = pyfftw.builders.ifftn(
                    self.fft_A_obj.get_output_array(), s=shape,
                    threads=threads)

        else:
            self.fft_A_obj = pyfftw.builders.rfftn(
                    A, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.fft_B_obj = pyfftw.builders.rfftn(
                    B, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.ifft_obj = pyfftw.builders.irfftn(
                    self.fft_A_obj.get_output_array(), s=shape,
                    threads=threads)

    def __call__(self, A, B):

        fft_padded_A = self.fft_A_obj(A)
        fft_padded_B = self.fft_B_obj(B)

        return self.ifft_obj(fft_padded_A * fft_padded_B)
```

This is used as:

```
custom_fft_conv = CustomFFTConvolution(A, B)
C = custom_fft_conv(A, B) # This can contain different values to during construction
```

with an optional `threads` argument when constructing the class. The purpose of creating a class is to benefit from the ability of FFTW to plan the transform in advance.

The full demo code below simply extends [@Kelsey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15075511/709852) for the timing and so on.

The speedup is substantial over both the numba solution and the vanilla fftconvolve solution. For n = 33, it's about 40-45x faster than both.

```
from timeit import Timer
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
from numba import jit, double
import pyfftw

# Original code
def custom_convolution(A, B):

    dimA = A.shape[0]
    dimB = B.shape[0]
    dimC = dimA + dimB

    C = np.zeros((dimC, dimC, dimC))
    for x1 in range(dimA):
        for x2 in range(dimB):
            for y1 in range(dimA):
                for y2 in range(dimB):
                    for z1 in range(dimA):
                        for z2 in range(dimB):
                            x = x1 + x2
                            y = y1 + y2
                            z = z1 + z2
                            C[x, y, z] += A[x1, y1, z1] * B[x2, y2, z2]
    return C

# Numba'ing the function with the JIT compiler
numba_convolution = jit(double[:, :, :](double[:, :, :],
                        double[:, :, :]))(custom_convolution)

def fft_convolution(A, B):
    return fftconvolve(A, B, mode='full')

class CustomFFTConvolution(object):

    def __init__(self, A, B, threads=1):

        shape = (np.array(A.shape) + np.array(B.shape))-1

        if np.iscomplexobj(A) and np.iscomplexobj(B):
            self.fft_A_obj = pyfftw.builders.fftn(
                    A, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.fft_B_obj = pyfftw.builders.fftn(
                    B, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.ifft_obj = pyfftw.builders.ifftn(
                    self.fft_A_obj.get_output_array(), s=shape,
                    threads=threads)

        else:
            self.fft_A_obj = pyfftw.builders.rfftn(
                    A, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.fft_B_obj = pyfftw.builders.rfftn(
                    B, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.ifft_obj = pyfftw.builders.irfftn(
                    self.fft_A_obj.get_output_array(), s=shape,
                    threads=threads)

    def __call__(self, A, B):

        fft_padded_A = self.fft_A_obj(A)
        fft_padded_B = self.fft_B_obj(B)

        return self.ifft_obj(fft_padded_A * fft_padded_B)

def run_test():
    reps = 10
    nt, ft, cft, cft2 = [], [], [], []
    x = range(2, 34)

    for N in x:
        print N
        A = np.random.rand(N, N, N)
        B = np.random.rand(N, N, N)

        custom_fft_conv = CustomFFTConvolution(A, B)
        custom_fft_conv_nthreads = CustomFFTConvolution(A, B, threads=2)

        C1 = numba_convolution(A, B)
        C2 = fft_convolution(A, B)
        C3 = custom_fft_conv(A, B)
        C4 = custom_fft_conv_nthreads(A, B)

        assert np.allclose(C1[:-1, :-1, :-1], C2)
        assert np.allclose(C1[:-1, :-1, :-1], C3)
        assert np.allclose(C1[:-1, :-1, :-1], C4)

        t = Timer(lambda: numba_convolution(A, B))
        nt.append(t.timeit(number=reps))
        t = Timer(lambda: fft_convolution(A, B))
        ft.append(t.timeit(number=reps))
        t = Timer(lambda: custom_fft_conv(A, B))
        cft.append(t.timeit(number=reps))
        t = Timer(lambda: custom_fft_conv_nthreads(A, B))
        cft2.append(t.timeit(number=reps))

    plt.plot(x, ft, label='scipy.signal.fftconvolve')
    plt.plot(x, nt, label='custom numba convolve')
    plt.plot(x, cft, label='custom pyfftw convolve')
    plt.plot(x, cft2, label='custom pyfftw convolve with threading')        
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_test()
```

**EDIT:** [More recent scipy does a better job of not always padding to powers of 2 length](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3144) so is closer in output to the pyFFTW case.

Comment: Awarded for comprehensiveness, general principles and comparison of different methods. Well done! And well done to all the great answers here!

Answer (score 3):

The Numba method above is a neat trick, but will only be an advantage for relatively small N.  An *O(N^6)* algorithm will kill you every time, regardless of how fast it is implemented.  In my tests, the `fftconvolve` method crosses over to be faster around N=20, and by N=32 is 10x as fast.  Leaving out the definition of `custom_convolution` above:

```
from timeit import Timer
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
from numba import jit, double

# Numba'ing the function with the JIT compiler
numba_convolution = jit(double[:, :, :](double[:, :, :],
                        double[:, :, :]))(custom_convolution)

def fft_convolution(A, B):
    return fftconvolve(A, B, mode='full')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reps = 3
    nt, ft = [], []
    x = range(2, 34)
    for N in x:
        print N
        A = np.random.rand(N, N, N)
        B = np.random.rand(N, N, N)
        C1 = numba_convolution(A, B)
        C2 = fft_convolution(A, B)
        assert np.allclose(C1[:-1, :-1, :-1], C2)
        t = Timer(lambda: numba_convolution(A, B))
        nt.append(t.timeit(number=reps))
        t = Timer(lambda: fft_convolution(A, B))
        ft.append(t.timeit(number=reps))
    plt.plot(x, ft, x, nt)
    plt.show()
```

It is also very dependent on N, since the FFT will be a lot faster for powers of 2.  The time for the FFT version is essentially constant for N=17 to N=32, and it is still faster at N=33, where it starts diverging quickly again.

You could try wrapping an FFT implementation in Numba, but you can't do that directly with the scipy version.

(Sorry to create a new answer, but I don't have the points to reply directly.)

Comment: That's a good followup and it makes sense that the FFT code would be faster for larger N. I only tested it up to 30, 30, 30 as the custom convolution function was taking too long on my computer.

Comment: Things are hotting up. The fftconvolve is nice.