# What is the equivalent of matlab's smooth3 function in python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I couldn't find an equivalent of matlab's smooth3 in python. How do you perform 3d smoothing in python?

Comment: You can convolve with a 3-D Gaussian. 
See [here][1] how to do that... 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786920/convolution-of-two-three-dimensional-arrays-with-padding-on-one-side-too-slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to use [`scipy.ndimage`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) for this.  It has a ton of functionality, and it gives you excellent control over memory usage (for example, you could do all of these operations in-place, without making a copy).

The equivalent of the default filter for `smooth3d` would be [`scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter(data, 3)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter) ("3" is the size of the filter. 3 is matlab's default).

The equivalent of `smooth3(data, 'gaussian')` would be [`scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(data, 3)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter).

Note that `scipy.ndimage`'s functions work for any dimensional data. I'll show a 2D example below for easier visualization, but the function call would be identical for 1D, 3D, 4D, 10D, etc.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

raw_data = np.random.random((30,30))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

axes[0].imshow(raw_data, interpolation='nearest')
axes[0].set(title='Raw Data', xticks=[], yticks=[])

axes[1].imshow(ndimage.uniform_filter(raw_data, 3), interpolation='nearest')
axes[1].set(title='Uniform Filter', xticks=[], yticks=[])

axes[2].imshow(ndimage.gaussian_filter(raw_data, 3), interpolation='nearest')
axes[2].set(title='Gaussian Filter', xticks=[], yticks=[])

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]